# using Java Stream without the filter() operation to block the stream

Tags: java, concurrency, java-stream, stream-processing

I'm working on a service that needs to make some stream processing for products.

Given a `Company` we can use `getProducts(Company company)` to get `List<Product>`.

The next thing I'd like to do is to filter that list. For each product I make a query to a DB to check if I already processed the given product.

So we have something like:

```
        companies
                .stream()
                .flatMap(this::getProducts)
                .filter(this::alreadyProcessed)
```

The next thing I'd like to do is to map each `Product` to `CompleteableFuture` that will handle the rest of the processing, asynchronously.

**Now for the problem:**

It's not really a stream processing in the sense that the `map()` to a `CompletableFuture` won't happen until the `filter()` operation is done.

I think I can:

1. use `parallelStream`, but that doesn't really solve the problem
2. I can instead of the above code, map a `Product` to a `CompletableFuture<Optional<Product>>` but this is quite annoying as the downstream would have to deal with a lot of empty `Optional`'s

What is the appropriate way to write this kind of stream processing in a way that won't block the chain of operations?

Comment: There might be a third option, executing a single SQL query to get all processed product of the given company

Comment: If you want to write a "chain of operations" with support for asynchronous behaviour, you should switch to more reactive libraries like `reactor`, `rxJava` or `Kotlin Coroutines`?

Comment: @AlexRudenko, yeah, my bad. It's supposed to be `flatMap`

Comment: what if you do : `.map(p -> { CompletableFuture<CompletableFuture<Product>> nested = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> { if(isAlreadyProcessed(p)){ return CompletableFuture.failedFuture(new RuntimeException()); } return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(p); }); return nested.thenCompose(Function.identity()); })` this way all subsequent code has to deal with `CompletableFuture<Product>`, of course some of those being failed.

Comment: Thanks @Eugene, I'll try this approach!